# Can't use select of angular material

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

Whenever I try to use "select" from angular material(https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview), I get this error.
I imported MatSelectModule though.

core.js:6272 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RootModule)[InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you export your material imports to another module, just try,
Import MatSelectModule into AppModule.